# ClassCastException: org.apache.drill.exec.expr.holders.NullableDateHolder cannot be cast to org.apache.drill.exec.expr.holders.DateHolder

Tags: parquet, apache-drill

This exception gives me Drill v. 1.16 when trying to query a parquet with WHERE clause on Date field.

```sql
select * FROM dfs.test."my/parquet/directory"
where "Date" >= '2019-11-01'
limit 10;
```

> ClassCastException: org.apache.drill.exec.expr.holders.NullableDateHolder cannot be cast to org.apache.drill.exec.expr.holders.DateHolder

Details:

```sql
select min("Date") as min, max("Date") as max
FROM dfs.test."my/parquet/directory";
---
min,max
2017-02-03,2019-12-05
```

```sql
select distinct sqltypeof("Date") as test
FROM dfs.test."my/parquet/directory";
---
test
DATE
```

---

After couple hours of debugging I found out that when I set `drill.exec.functions.cast_empty_string_to_null` to FALSE, this starts to work. But I cannot let this option be FALSE.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a workaround:

```sql
WHERE "Date" >= DATE_ADD('2019-11-01', 0)
```

It's hideous but it fixes the behavior. If you find better way, share it.

-- UPDATE

Still broken. Applies to versions 1.16, 1.17, 1.19

Comment: I think that where ``date` >= date '2019-11-01'` is another workaround.